# Install PDO_OCI on PHP7

Tags: php, linux, pdo, driver, oci8

He,

I try since several days to install PDO_OCI on PHP7 on a new server.
I have ever on other server PDO_OCI but on PHP 5.4, and all is good, not problem with this version.

I have the message :

```
:/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0# make
/bin/bash /home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/libtool --mode=compile cc -I -I. 
-I/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC 
-I/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/include 
-I/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/main 
-I/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0 
-I/usr/include/php/20151012 
-I/usr/include/php/20151012/main 
-I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM 
-I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend 
-I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext 
-I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib 
-I/usr/lib/oracle/instantclient/include/oracle/12.1/client  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c 
/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c -o oci_driver.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I -I. 
-I/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0 -DPHP_ATOM_INC 
-I/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/include 
-I/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/main 
-I/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0 
-I/usr/include/php/20151012 
-I/usr/include/php/20151012/main 
-I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM 
-I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend 
-I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext 
-I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib 
-I/usr/lib/oracle/instantclient/include/oracle/12.1/client -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c 
/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci_driver.o

/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c: In function 'pdo_oci_fetch_error_func':
/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c:51:3: error: 
too many arguments to function 'add_next_index_string' add_next_index_string(info, einfo->errmsg, 1);

In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:39:0,
                 from /home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c:25:
/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_API.h:432:14: note: declared here
 ZEND_API int add_next_index_string(zval *arg, const char *str);
              ^
/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c: In function 'oci_handle_preparer':
/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c:238:59: warning: passing argument 5 of 'pdo_parse_params' from incompatible pointer type
  ret = pdo_parse_params(stmt, (char*)sql, sql_len, &nsql, &nsql_len TSRMLS_CC);
                                                       ^
In file included from /home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c:29:0:
/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/pdo/php_pdo_driver.h:678:13: note: expected 'size_t *' but argument is of type 'int *'
 PDO_API int pdo_parse_params(pdo_stmt_t *stmt, char *inquery, size_t inquery_len,
         ^
/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c: At top level:
/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c:411:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
  oci_handle_preparer,
 ^
/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c:411:2: warning: (near initialization for 'oci_methods.preparer')
/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c:412:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
  oci_handle_doer,
  ^
/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c:412:2: warning: (near initialization for 'oci_methods.doer')
/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c:413:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
  oci_handle_quoter,
  ^
/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c:413:2: warning: (near initialization for 'oci_methods.quoter')
Makefile:198: recipe for target 'oci_driver.lo' failed
make: *** [oci_driver.lo] Error 1
```

My configuration :
Linux server System     Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u4 (2016-02-29) x86_64 
PHP PHP Version 7.0.4-1~dotdeb+8.1
PDO drivers     mysql 
OCI8 Support    enabled (is work).

I have read PDO_OCI is include on PHP7 https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-7.0.7/ext/pdo_oci
but how activate it ?

My code to PHP 5.4 doesn't work on this server PHP7.

Somebody have a solution ?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

Download the source files of your PHP (get URL from https://www.php.net/downloads, e.g. https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.16.tar.bz2):

```sh
PHP_VERSION=7.3.27 # Set to your PHP version

cd /tmp
sudo apt-get install php-dev -y
wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.gz
tar xvfj php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.bz2
rm php-${PHP_VERSION}.tar.bz2
```

Copy `pdo_oci` into `/tmp`:

```sh
cp -r /tmp/php-${PHP_VERSION}/ext/pdo_oci /tmp
cd /tmp/pdo_oci
```

Build plugin:

```sh
sudo phpize
sudo ./configure --enable-option-checking=fatal # Optionally add more parameters
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Finall, create and link files:

```sh
sudo echo "extension=pdo_oci.so" > /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/pdo_oci.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/pdo_oci.ini /etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_oci.ini
```

Restart apache2

Answer (score 0):

[This extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_OCI) has been abandoned and won't compile. Why? PHP's API has changed significantly in version 7; the error you are seeing indicates that internal function signatures have changed:

```
/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c: In function 'pdo_oci_fetch_error_func':
/home/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_driver.c:51:3: error: 
too many arguments to function 'add_next_index_string' add_next_index_string(info, einfo->errmsg, 1);
```

How to fix this depends on how you installed PHP. I will hope you compiled it yourself, since you are doing the same for extensions. If so, just [recompile using `--with-pdo-oci=DIR`](http://www.php.net/pdo_oci) where `DIR` is the Oracle home directory.

If you installed from a package via `apt`, you've got a few choices. 1) see if you can get get a PDO-OCI driver the same way (doesn't look like there is one.) 2) remove your packages and do everything from source. 3) Try a [third-party driver](https://github.com/yajra/pdo-via-oci8).

Comment: I have test https://github.com/taq/pdooci but i have a lot of code to rewritting. I can connecte and print info with the soluction but i can't rewritte all my code. I thinks the best way for me is install PDO_OCI on version 7 php. Anybody have a tuto for that ? I haven't see it on the web. Somebody have install PDO_OCI on PHP7 and it is works ?